# index is not changing every loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

I want to have a function call for every number in an array. I also want some values to depend on what number of loop you are on (index) and what number you are on. (item). It successfully determines which item i am on, so I did not include that part of code but the index one always shows up as zero even though its on the second or third loop. If I console.log beat it always shows up as eb1b05, and if i console.log index it always shows up as zero

```
bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction);

function foreachfunction(item, index) {
  let intervals = [fifthfunction, fourthfunction];
  let interval = intervals[Math.floor(Math.random() * intervals.length)]
  interval();

  if (interval == fifthfunction) {
    findnotefifth()
  }
  if (interval == fourthfunction) {
    findnotefourth()
  }

  function findnotefifth() {
    let beat = eb1b05

    if (index == 0) {
      beat = eb1b05
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      beat = eb1b1
    }
    if (index == 2) {
      beat = eb1b15
    }
    if (index == 3) {
      beat = eb1b2
    }

    function findnotefourth() {
      let beat = eb1b05

      if (index == 0) {
        beat = eb1b05
      }
      if (index == 1) {
        beat = eb1b1
      }
      if (index == 2) {
        beat = eb1b15
      }
      if (index == 3) {
        beat = eb1b2
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `}` at the end of `foreachfunction`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.